# Student Visa Germany

Tags: germany, student-visa, criminal-records

My friend was convicted for DUI, his BAC was 0.047, legal limit in India is 0.03%, he was fined for DUI, I was riding pillion with him and I was also fined for negligence. I will be applying for student visa for Germany. There's is a question on Visa form " Have you been convicted?", will this incident cause an issue in the Visa coming through.

Comment: Your question invites opinion-based answers.  You’ve already seen this https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/16110/germany-work-visa-with-drunk-driving-conviction, i doubt anyone can give you a better, definitive answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, let's  see if anyone's got any other opinion, viewpoints shared on the question you linked are quite assuring though

Comment: If the guy who asked that question got the VISA, it would be a huge sigh of relief for me.